# ToList vs ToList tipado

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expressões-lambda

Eu estava revisando alguns métodos de um projeto ASP.NET MVC e encontrei alguns casos em que é usado apenas `.ToList()` e outros em que é usado `.ToList<type>()` (onde *type* é um tipo de objeto usado no contexto).

Imagine que apenas com o `.ToList()` você já teria uma lista com o tipo que você precisa, por qual motivo usaria um `ToList()` tipado?

Veja o exemplo:

Obs: A propriedade `PessoaId` é do tipo inteiro.

```
var pessoasIds = db.Pessoa.Select(p => p.PessoaId).ToList();
```

Mesmo exemplo tipado:

```
var pessoasIds = db.Pessoa.Select(p => p.PessoaId).ToList<int>();
```

Existe alguma diferença em termos de desempenho por exemplo?

A dúvida também se estende para outros métodos, como `.ToArray()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, os dois são a mesma coisa, pois o código gerado será o mesmo.

Só faz sentido utilizar o método tipado se você deseja especificar um tipo diferente do `IEnumerable`. Fora isso, você não precisa especificá-lo.

Caso queira, a implementação do método `.ToList()` está no [no site da Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx), que é este abaixo:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source
)
```

> Existe alguma diferença em termos de desempenho por exemplo?

Não, o código gerado será o mesmo.

Traduzindo as palavras do [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33544161/4843158):

> Por exemplo, suponha que você possui um `IEnumerable<string>` e deseja criar um `List<T>`. Caso queira uma `List<string>`, basta utilizar o `.ToList()`. Se você deseja usar *[Covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)* e obter obter um `List<object>`, utilize o `ToList<object>`
>
> Veja o exemplo abaixo:
>
> ```
> IEnumerable<string> strings = new [] { "foo" };
> List<string> stringList = strings.ToList();
> List<object> objectList = strings.ToList<object>();
> ```

Answer (score 4):

O normal é usar o `ToList()`, o compilador infere o tipo e tudo funciona. Mas e se você quiser que a lista seja de um tipo diferente, compatível, claro, o que fazer? Tem que especificar que tipo deseja que seja a lista.

Se esse `PessoaId` já é um `int` não tem vantagem alguma usá-lo a não ser deixar mais explícito no código. Mas vamos dizer que quisesse guardar na lista como `object`, então seria necessário fazer `ToList<object>()`.